# How to fix I/O operation on closed file?

Tags: python, io

I have the following code:

```
with open("Berry2019_Table1.txt", "r") as datafile:
    print (datafile.read().split()[11::4])

mass = datafile.read().split()[11::4]
```

It gives me the I/O operation error. I'm trying to put the list of values into a variable, so how should I go about fixing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should indent your last line. If you open file using `with` you can't access the file outside `with` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are trying to call the file outside of the `loop` as you are using `with` you should perform all operation withing the `loop`. So, instead use:

```
with open("Berry2019_Table1.txt", "r") as datafile:
    print (datafile.read().split()[11::4])

    mass = datafile.read().split()[11::4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation.
Your "mass = datafile.read..." should be within the "with open(..." as you're trying to call datafile from out of the withas statement.

Answer (score 0):

do as follows:

```
with open("Berry2019_Table1.txt", "r") as datafile:
    print (datafile.read().split()[11::4])
    mass = datafile.read().split()[11::4]
```

outside the `with` block `datafile` will be closed, and so, you won't be able to access it...